# Не могу обратиться к полю таблицы

Tags: php, sql, yii2

```
$model = Images::find()
->where(['product_id' => $id])
->joinWith(['product' => function ($q) {
    $q->from('product');
}])
->all();

if (Yii::$app->user->can('updateFabricatorImages', ['brand_id' => $model->product->brand_id])) { code }

Trying to get property 'product' of non-object
```

В чем причина?

var_dump($model);:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(frontend\models\Images)#128 (11) {
    ["image"]=>
    NULL
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(5)
      ["url"]=>
      string(9) "115_0.jpg"
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(115)
      ["deleted"]=>
      NULL
      ["main"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(5)
      ["url"]=>
      string(9) "115_0.jpg"
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(115)
      ["deleted"]=>
      NULL
      ["main"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["product"]=>
      object(frontend\models\Products)#137 (10) {
        ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(5) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(115)
          ["name"]=>
          string(2) "wr"
          ["created_at"]=>
          int(1537185812)
          ["updated_at"]=>
          int(1537431514)
          ["brand_id"]=>
          int(4)
        }
        ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(5) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(115)
          ["name"]=>
          string(2) "wr"
          ["created_at"]=>
          int(1537185812)
          ["updated_at"]=>
          int(1537431514)
          ["brand_id"]=>
          int(4)
        }
        ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
        NULL
        ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
        NULL
        ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
        string(7) "default"
        ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
        array(2) {
          ["beforeInsert"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                object(yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior)#138 (7) {
                  ["createdAtAttribute"]=>
                  string(10) "created_at"
                  ["updatedAtAttribute"]=>
                  string(10) "updated_at"
                  ["value"]=>
                  NULL
                  ["attributes"]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["beforeInsert"]=>
                    array(2) {
                      [0]=>
                      string(10) "created_at"
                      [1]=>
                      string(10) "updated_at"
                    }
                    ["beforeUpdate"]=>
                    string(10) "updated_at"
                  }
                  ["skipUpdateOnClean"]=>
                  bool(true)
                  ["preserveNonEmptyValues"]=>
                  bool(false)
                  ["owner"]=>
                  *RECURSION*
                }
                [1]=>
                string(18) "evaluateAttributes"
              }
              [1]=>
              NULL
            }
          }
          ["beforeUpdate"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                object(yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior)#138 (7) {
                  ["createdAtAttribute"]=>
                  string(10) "created_at"
                  ["updatedAtAttribute"]=>
                  string(10) "updated_at"
                  ["value"]=>
                  NULL
                  ["attributes"]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["beforeInsert"]=>
                    array(2) {
                      [0]=>
                      string(10) "created_at"
                      [1]=>
                      string(10) "updated_at"
                    }
                    ["beforeUpdate"]=>
                    string(10) "updated_at"
                  }
                  ["skipUpdateOnClean"]=>
                  bool(true)
                  ["preserveNonEmptyValues"]=>
                  bool(false)
                  ["owner"]=>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $model = Products::find()
    ->joinWith('images')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете `->all()` что возвращает массив объектов. И у массива пытаетесь получить свойство объекта: `$model->product->brand_id`.
Даже `var_dump` выводит Вам массив.

Comment: что мне нужно сделать, чтобы получить нужное свойство из связанной таблицы?

Comment: Мда.. `->one()`

Comment: джойн не работает с one

Comment: На Ваш вопрос "В чем причина?" я ответил, дальше сами смотрите

Comment: А нужен ли там джойн, если нужен one? Смысл джойна в том, чтобы слепить одну таблицу из двух. Если нужен one, тогда просто реляцией получаем необходимые данные. Там по сути джоин из коробки.